# Delphi Win32 Programming/Access Violation problems

Tags: delphi

I wasn't entirely sure how to name this, so apologies in advance.

You see, I'm trying to teach myself Win32/DirectX programming, utilizing Delphi (my language of choice) using this site - http://rastertek.com/tutindex.html

Of course, the site being all in C++, I have to port it to Delphi. It seemed simple enough, at first. I'm on the second tutorial for DirectX 11 - setting up the framework and getting the initial window to show up.

Now for my actual problem. I was getting Access Violation errors. So I found and started to use MadExcept to try and find out what was going on. So it tells me the lines, but I'm clueless as to how to solve the issues at hand.

I have everything set up to mimic as well as I can the original source code. The only real difference being that in the instances where a pointer to a class for a variable, such as the case with m_input, m_grahics, and system, I made a type for those. So I have the TSystemClass, TInputClass, TGraphicsClass, and then I have PSystemClass, etc. that = ^TSystemClass, etc. I figured that this would make things a bit simpler and more neater. On a side note, I assume it should be said, but I for the construction of the copy constructors made the initial classes inherit from TPersistent so I could use it's Assign procedure.

So, back to the Access Violation errors. So first, the problem was in the main program with system being of type PSystemClass. So for a reason unknown to me, when I tried to use system.create, it was at that very instant, creating the access violation. I then realized however that I wasn't assigning system the system.create. So I tried this, and it said that, and rightfully so I suppose, at compile time an error that the two were incompatible since system.create is of type TSystemClass, and system is of PSystemClass. So I tried typecasting it, and that worked. but once again, still getting the dreaded access violations.

So then I had an odd idea, maybe I should call the regular constructor right from the TSystemClass itself. And I tried, needed to typecast again. So I did. And it worked! No longer an access violation error there! Now... New problem! Or rather in this case "problems". There's 3 things now listed in the call stack in MadExcept. The first one:

```
m_hinstance := GetModuleHandle(nil);
```

It's saying that this is causing an access violation error. Though why is this, exactly? From what I understand and have read, if GetModuleHandle is set to null/nil, it should retrieve the handle for the file that called it, right? And from what the documentation says, that should be executable.

However note: I'm not sure if the fact that I have the main program, the systemclass stuff, the inputclass stuff, and the graphicsclass stuff, all in different program/unit files to mimic the nature of the original source code. So is this possibly what's causing it? And if so how would I fix it? By putting all of the code from the unit files into the main program file? Though that, in my own personal opinion, would be quite messy and unintuitive.

The next one baffles me even more.

```
InitializeWindows(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
```

I'm not dealing with anything other then a function to register the window class and set things up for the window and all here. So I'm not quite sure what the problem here is since it only deals with 2 parameters and they're defined and all already before it's called. So I'm not quite sure what the problem here is at all and what exactly is causing the access violation.

and then finally the final one is in the main program:

```
return := system.initialize;
```

Return is what I used in all instances of the result variable of the original source code, as result is of course a built in variable of all functions.

I suppose if system is never able to properly do what it's meant to do then something could/should happen here. Likewise, because I used TSystemClass.Create (typecasted to PSystemClass) earlier to create system would that do anything here? And is it possibly linked to the other two because they're not able to do their own thing properly?

And on a final note; there is one last thing actually on the call stack in MadExcept.

It says Kernel32.dll in the module section, but aside from the main thread, it lists nothing else. (If this information is needed I'll gladly put it up).

Thanks in advance to anyone who's read this far and I hope to find some help on this problem so I may further my studies.

Comment: This too narrative. The few code samples you've got are embedded in long paragraphs of text. Posting some code is shorter, easier to read, and less error-prone then saying narrating your use of typecasting.

Comment: And to give some tips: When you declare a variable of type TSomething (where TSomething is a class), it's already an pointer: Take that into consideration when porting C++ code. When you say `^TSomething` it's like saying `TSomething **` in C++ (double pointer). If you hard-cast `TSomething` to `^TSomething` you're of course going to get in trouble. In C++ terms, you've just casted `TSomething *` to `TSomething **`. And the location where an Access Violation "pops" is not always indicative for the cause of the error. Try using FASTMM4 with Full Debug to diagnose AV's and memory corruption.

Comment: we're not going to email you. We night be able to help you if you showed some code.

Comment: we're not going to email you, but the spammers will.

Comment: @Asurai Valentine, I have removed the email addresses. We like to keep all information on stackoverflow for future references. Besides we don't like to facilitate spammers.

Comment: I can look at your code when I am home, but my guess is that Cosmin Prund is right and your are messing up with class variables and pointers. The access violation `m_hinstance := GetModuleHandle(nil);` could be explained if you are calling Initialize on a class reference that is nil or invalid. The AV is not caused by the GetModuleHandle call, but by assigning the result of GetModuleHandle to m_hinstance.

Comment: @Gamecat ah, I see. Thank you. I wasn't sure if people would have preferred that instead. So it's why I included them. Once again, thank you, for correcting me. Also, as I'm unsure of this, should I take the previous comments I've made and put them all into a single answer instead and delete the comments? I was unsure of what to do there as a "comment" felt a more appropriate name for them and they're not really an "answer" at all.

Comment: @The_Fox Well, I've tweaked the code a bit, removed the instances of PSystem/Input/GraphicsClass and used the regular TSystem/Input/GraphicsClass versions in their place. And it appears as though now the situation has changed, as now in the callstack it is referencing the constructor, more specifically the line that sets a private variable called m_graphics to nil. It strikes me as odd because I would assume it would do the same with m_input, another private variable, however according to the call stack from MadExcept it is not. And thank you for the advice, of course!

Comment: @Asurai Valentine: If you have additional info, put that in your question. Do not bundle your comments and put them in an answer when they are not an answer. Answers are only used for answers, not for providing additional info.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the information! Now I'm very much so more informed then before. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're instantiating your classes all wrong. Here's an example from `TSystemClass.Initialize`:

```
m_Input := PInputClass(m_Input.create);
```

That's a variable you declared as a `PInputClass`.

Earlier, in `TSystemClass.Create`, you initialized that variable:

```
m_Input := nil;
```

So, since you have a null reference, it should be clear that you can't call any methods on it. In particular, you cannot call `Create` on it. Instead, call `Create` on the *class* you want to instantiate: `TInputClass.Create`.

That constructor returns a value of the type you constructed, a `TInputClass`. It doesn't return a `PInputClass`, so your type-cast is wrong. As Cosmin's comment explains, Delphi object variables are *already* pointers. It's exceedingly rare to have to declare a pointer type based on Delphi classes. The correct code is this:

```
m_Input := TInputClass.Create;
```

After that line, you check whether `m_Input` is null. You never have to do that in Delphi; a constructor either returns a valid object, or it doesn't return at all. If there's a problem constructing an object, the constructor throws an exception and the assignment statement never executes. (The original C++ code does it wrong, too. The `new` operator hasn't returned a null pointer on failure for over a decade, long before anyone was in a position to start writing a DirectX 11 tutorial.)

Comment: Am I missing something obvious? Where is the code to which you refer?

Comment: I see, that was quite insightful! Thanks a trillion! So, now I believe I have all of my classes instantiated correctly. Though now I still recieve something in the call stack in MadExcept about the constructor of the TSystemClass. Regardless of order the first bit of code after Inherited; is always the culprit. and if I take out the nil assignments to m_input and m_graphics, then it seems to complain about the end; of the constructor.

Comment: @David, Asurai gave a MediaFire link in a comment on Fmotis's answer.

Comment: Asurai, what "something" do you receive? I can neither compile nor execute your code, so you need to do the investigation yourself. My first thought is that you've fixed your instantiation problems in *SystemClass.pas* but have not yet fixed how you instantiate `TSystemClass` itself in *main.dpr*.

Comment: Though I have an updated link now - not much changes but it's the ones I mentioned before at least. http://www.mediafire.com/?z9g51zlrb89d998 and here's an image of the call stack. Probably alot easier then me explaining it. (Plus I'm not that great with words) http://i252.photobucket.com/albums/hh33/Asurai_Asureflame/MadExcept_CallStack.png

Comment: Like I said, you're instantiating the system class wrong in *main.dpr*: `system := system.create`. Create that object the same way you create all other objects in all other Delphi programs you've ever written: `TSystemClass.Create`. I advise against using "system" as a variable name; it hides the System unit.

Comment: and I foolishly looked over that. Apologies. But after that it works now! Though I do get an exception thrown when escape is pressed. Though I'd probably say that if I can't figure that out then it's time for another question. Thanks a ton, Rob! you're a real life saver. And jeebus do you guys here work fast o.o Elsewehre it'd probably have taken forever to get this far along~

Answer (score 2):

You should first of all try to get rid of the TPersistent inheritance. If you want to pass an object to a library its interface should be exactly the same as the original that is used in C++. By inheriting from TPersistent you take a whole lot of load into your class that might be not needed or might even be the reason of your problems.

Additionally it would help if you posted the exact output of the exceptions. Or even the CallStack. That might help tracing down the error.

Comment: Apologies for the super long narrative, everyone. However I felt as though I needed explanation behind everything and felt that simply posting 300+ lines of code or some such would be of any help to anyone. Though I apologize again for the very small code snippets. And here's a media fire link to my entire project. http://www.mediafire.com/?82w27c08d4fk6tg I've taken out the pointer classes, as well as the copy constructors. I've no clue if they'll ever be implemented, but if they are I'll deal with it then. Thank you everyone so far for the advice!